# Ruby parsing and regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Picked up Ruby recently and have been fiddling around with it. I wanted to learn how to use regex or other Ruby tricks to check for certain words, whitespace characters, valid format etc in a given text line.

Let's say I have an order list that looks strictly like this in this format:

```
cost: 50 items: book,lamp
```

One space after semicolon, no space after each comma, no trailing whitespaces at the end and stuff like that.
How can I check for errors in this format using Ruby? This for example should fail my checks:

```
cost:     60 items:shoes,football
```

My goal was to split the string by a " " and check to see if the first word was "cost:", if the second word was a number and so on but I realized that splitting on a " " doesn't help me check for extra whitespaces as it just eats it up. Also doesn't help me check for trailing whitespaces. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: However you do it, this is a very nice example for developing your TDD (test driven development)/testing skills. At time of commenting, I would propose that you go ahead and spend some time playing with `minitest` and your problem.

Comment: `:` is a colon. `;` is a semi-colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression.

```
r = /
    \A                # match beginning of string     
    cost:\s           # match "cost:" followed by a space
    \d+\s             # match > 0 digits followed by a space
    items:\s          # match "items:" followed by a space
    [[:alpha:]]+      # match > 0 lowercase or uppercase letters
    (?:,[[:alpha:]]+) # match a comma followed by > 0 lowercase or uppercase 
                      # letters in a non-capture group (?: ... )
    *                 # perform the match on non-capture group >= 0 times
    \z                # match the end of the string
    /x                # free-spacing regex definition mode

"cost: 50 items: book,lamp"         =~ r #=> 0   (a match, beginning at index 0)
"cost: 50 items: book,lamp,table"   =~ r #=> 0   (a match, beginning at index 0)
"cost:     60 items:shoes,football" =~ r #=> nil (no match)
```

The regex can can of course be written in the normal manner:

```
r = /\Acost:\s\d+\sitems:\s[[:alpha:]]+(?:,[[:alpha:]]+)*\z/
```

or

```
r = /\Acost: \d+ items: [[:alpha:]]+(?:,[[:alpha:]]+)*\z/
```

though a whitespace character (`\s`) cannot be replaced by a space in the free-spacing mode definition (`\x`).

Comment: To explicitly match a space in free-spacing mode you could use `\ ` or `\u0020` or `[ ]`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. Just pushing this further, is there a way to include the presence of underscores and numbers and hyphens (No spaces) in the items list? Like if the item was a "version_2_vaccuum" instead of something simple like "lamp". Will adding a "\w" after the [:alpha:] work?

Comment: Just change `[[:alpha:]]+` in the regex to `\w+` in both places (`\w` being a "word character", which is an uppercase or lowercase letter, digit or underscore).